# A question about Laurent series.

Tags: complex-analysis

$p(z)=a^2z+bz+c$, how to get the Laurent series of $\frac{p(z)}{z-1}$ in $\mathbb C\setminus\{1\}$? ($a$ is not equal to zero)

Comment: Do you mean $p(z) = az^2 + bz + c$?

Comment: Taylor expand $p(z)$ about $z=1.$

Comment: What @spaceisdarkgreen said.. Add forms of 0: $$p(z)= a ((z-1) + 1)^2 + b((z-1)+1) + c,$$ now multiply these out and collect coefficients of powers of $(z-1)$.

Comment: By calculating the coefficients directly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series?

Answer (score 1):

You can guess that $p(z) = a(z-1)^2 + d(z-1) + e = az^2 + bz + c,$ and solve for $d,e$

You can find $p(z+1)$ and that will point you to the correct coefficients, too.

Or, you can find the quotient, $\frac {p(z)}{z-1} = q(z) + \frac {r}{z-1}$ and take the remainder.

Then divide the quotient of  $\frac {q(z)}{z-1}$ and take the remainder.

and the last quotient is the constant $a.$

These will be the coefficients of the $(z-1)^0, (z-1)^1, (z-1)^2$ terms, respectively

Answer (score 1):

Without solving any equation, you can find the coefficients  in  the expansion of $p(z)$ by  powers of $z-1$ by the *method of successive divisions* by $z-1$, exactly the same way as you find the expansion of a natural number in basis $b$  by successive divisions of its decimal expansion by the basis.

You should find
$$p(z)=(a+b+c) +(2a+b)(z-1)+a(z-1)^2,$$
so that
$$\frac{p(z)}{z-1}=\frac{a+b+c}{z-1} +(2a+b)+a(z-1).$$